# How to synchronize 2 databases

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, synchronization

I want to sync 2 database specific records.
Let suppose I have two databases;

```
1.Shop 
2.Stock
```

Now lets suppose user change the price of a specific product in stock. I want to change this product price in shop also!

What I work out is that - assuming Internet connection is stable,

- When price change in stock I invoke a web service this service will insert entries in web data table price.
- Now on shop side I ping that web data table using web service every 20 minutes if I find any new entry I update that relevant product price in shop!

Another option I thought about was replication. But we are using express edition of SQL Server and according to my knowledge express edition can not work as publisher!

Is my first option is efficient for this purpose or am I missing something and there is a better alternative to accomplish this purpose!

Comment: Replication or service broker are the obvious tools for this job, but as you've already identified, they need at least one non-express edition of SQL Server to work.

Comment: This *might* be one for dba.SE, but there may need to be a non-database coded solution if the OP's SQL versions can't do replication. So I'm leaving here for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a trigger on the table like pRime says above but instead of writing directly to the other database write the changes to a local "staging" table and then every 20 min or so schedule a task to send the updates to the second db.

You could set up the second DB as a Linked Server.

This way you avoid making the table the trigger is on Read Only if the connection between the two dbs goes down.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a trigger on Stock table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName
ON [Stock].[dbo].[products]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
IF ( UPDATE (productPrice))
BEGIN
    --insert to shop
END
GO
```

Comment: just out of curiousity - will this also work if the two databases are on a different server and/or behind a firewall ?

Comment: im not sure about the firewall, but for different servers (servers must be linked together) you can explicitly reference the tables as servername.databasename.tablename.. but this may have some performance issues... instead of that you can use replication...

Comment: I'd usually recommend against cross-*database* triggers, let alone cross-*server* - if the net connection goes down, you effectively make this table read-only, and the errors it produces will be fun.

Comment: @Damien What do you suggest? I'm really interested in this

Comment: @Uw - I'd strongly suggest moving up from Express edition to a version that supports replication and/or service broker, and then using either of those. Which one would depend on the frequency of updates, latency requirements, etc. Trying to build something robust yourself that will work well across firewalls, etc, and cope in the face of e.g. network drop outs, is usually too much effort, compared to tried and tested components.

Answer (score 0):

IF can't use the MS SQL Server replication feature (requires some non-Express edition as you already identified) for this situation (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) then another option is to use the **MS Sync Framework** (can work with DBs down to SQL CE etc., files even custom data sources etc.) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002.aspx .

IF you really want to implement this in code yourself (I strongly recommend against that) then implement it as a "push-scenario" :

- DB triggers which fill staging tables
- Windows Service which does check for changes in the staging tables and apply themn
- conflict resolution rules
- complete logging of all this to be able to analyze discrepancies (just in case)